# PHP Dynamic Database Insertion

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, post

I have a form with a row called `target1` and a JavaScript which adds rows dynamically i.e. `target2`,`target3` etc. and same for `strategy` and `resource`.

I want to enter these into a database using php and mysql. Because the amount of submitted rows is dynamic, i think i need a `foreach` statement or `while` loop.

I have attempted a foreach() with no luck.

Here is the code.

Dynamic row JavaScript/PHP File:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');
if($_REQUEST['type'] == "targets"){
?>
function addRowToTargetTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('targets');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration + ".");
  var targetid = document.createElement('input');
  targetid.type = 'hidden';
  targetid.name = 'target' + iteration;
  targetid.id = 'target' + iteration;
  targetid.value = 'target' + iteration;
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);
  cellLeft.appendChild(targetid);

  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.name = 'target' + iteration;
  el.id = 'target' + iteration;
  el.className = 'validate[required]';
  el.style.cssText="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;";
  cellRight.appendChild(el);

  // far right cell
  var cellFarRight = row.insertCell(2);
  var el2 = document.createElement('textarea');
  el2.name = 'targetcriteria' + iteration;
  el2.id = 'targetcriteria' + iteration;
  el2.className = 'validate[required]';
  el2.style.cssText="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;";
  cellFarRight.appendChild(el2);

}
function removeRowFromTargetTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('targets');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
<?php
}elseif($_REQUEST['type'] == "strategies"){
?>
function addRowToStrategyTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('strategies');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration + ".");
  var strategyid = document.createElement('input');
  strategyid.type = 'hidden';
  strategyid.name = 'strategy' + iteration;
  strategyid.id = 'strategy' + iteration;
  strategyid.value = 'strategy' + iteration;
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);
  cellLeft.appendChild(strategyid);

  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.name = 'strategy' + iteration;
  el.id = 'strategy' + iteration;
  el.className = 'validate[required]';
  el.style.cssText="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;";
  cellRight.appendChild(el);

}
function removeRowFromStrategyTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('strategies');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}

<?php }elseif($_REQUEST['type'] == "resources"){
?>
function addRowToResourceTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('resources');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
  var iteration = lastRow;
  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

  // left cell
  var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
  var textNode = document.createTextNode(iteration + ".");
  var resourceid = document.createElement('input');
  resourceid.type = 'hidden';
  resourceid.name = 'resource' + iteration;
  resourceid.id = 'resource' + iteration;
  resourceid.value = 'resource' + iteration;
  cellLeft.appendChild(textNode);
  cellLeft.appendChild(resourceid);

  // right cell
  var cellRight = row.insertCell(1);
  var el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.name = 'resource' + iteration;
  el.id = 'resource' + iteration
  el.style.cssText="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;";
  cellRight.appendChild(el);

}
function removeRowFromResourceTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('resources');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<div id="non-indent">
<form action="complete-iep-operations.php?operation=create&action=insert" method="post" id="validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="register" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr class="no-pointer">
    <th scope="col" width="48">
      <h4>IEP No.</h4>
    </th>  
    <th scope="col" width="153">
      <h4>IEP Date</h4>
    </th>
    <th scope="col" width="124">
      <h4>Renewal Date</h4>
    </th>
    <th scope="col" width="116">
      <h4>IEP Meeting Conducted</h4>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <p><input name="iep_number" type="text" id="iep_number" maxlength="2" class="validate[required]" style="margin-top:5px; width:40px;" /></p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>
      <input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:30px;" class="validate[required]" name="iep-day" id="iep-day" maxlength="2" />
      -
      <input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:30px;" class="validate[required]" name="iep-month" id="iep-day" maxlength="2" />
      -
      <input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:60px;" class="validate[required]" name="iep-year" id="iep-day" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>
      <input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:30px;" class="validate[required]" name="renewal-day" id="renewal-day" maxlength="2" />
-
<input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:30px;" class="validate[required]" name="renewal-month" id="renewal-day" maxlength="2" />
-
<input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:60px;" class="validate[required]" name="renewal-year" id="renewal-day" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    </td>
    <td>
    <p>
      <input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:30px;" class="validate[required]" name="completed-day3" id="completed-day3" maxlength="2" />
-
<input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:30px;" class="validate[required]" name="completed-day3" id="completed-day3" maxlength="2" />
-
<input type="text" style="margin-top:5px; width:60px;" class="validate[required]" name="completed-day3" id="completed-day3" maxlength="4" />
    </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<h3>Targets</h3>
<br />
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="targets" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr class="no-pointer">
    <th scope="col" width="102">
      <h4>Target Number</h4>
    </th>  
    <th scope="col">
      <h4>Target Details</h4>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <h4>Target Achievement Criteria</h4>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <p>1.</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="target1" id="target1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="target1"></label>
      <textarea name="target1" id="target1" class="validate[required]" style="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;"></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="targetcriteria1"></label>
      <textarea name="targetcriteria1" id="targetcriteria1" class="validate[required]" style="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="register" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
<div align="right">
<input type="button" value="Remove Target Row" id="submit" onclick="removeRowFromTargetTable();" style="margin:0px; margin-right:10px; float:right;" />
<input type="button" value="Add Another Target" id="submit" onclick="addRowToTargetTable();" style="margin:0px; margin-right:20px; float:right;" />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<h3>Strategies</h3>
<br />
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="strategies" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr class="no-pointer">
    <th scope="col" width="102">
      <h4>Strategy Number</h4>
    </th>  
    <th scope="col">
      <h4>Strategy Details</h4>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <p>1.</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="strategy1" id="strategy1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="strategy1"></label>
      <textarea name="strategy1" id="strategy1" class="validate[required]" style="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="register" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
<div align="right">
<input type="button" value="Remove Strategy Row" id="submit" onclick="removeRowFromStrategyTable();" style="margin:0px; margin-right:10px; float:right;" />
<input type="button" value="Add Another Strategy" id="submit" onclick="addRowToStrategyTable();" style="margin:0px; margin-right:20px; float:right;" />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<h3>Resources</h3>
<br />
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="resources" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr class="no-pointer">
    <th scope="col" width="102">
      <h4>Resource Number</h4>
    </th>  
    <th scope="col">
      <h4>Resource Details</h4>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <p>1.</p>
    <input type="hidden" value="resource1" id="resource1" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="resource1"></label>
      <textarea name="resource1" id="resource1" style="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;"></textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<table border="1" class="listing full" id="register" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
<div align="right">
<input type="button" value="Remove Resource Row" id="submit" onclick="removeRowFromResourceTable();" style="margin:0px; margin-right:10px; float:right;" />
<input type="button" value="Add Another Resource" id="submit" onclick="addRowToResourceTable();" style="margin:0px; margin-right:20px; float:right;" />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<table border="0" class="full" id="register" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
<td>
<div align="right">
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" style="margin:0px; margin-right:10px; float:right;" /></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

And the php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('host', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db401728075') or die(mysql_error());

if($_REQUEST['operation']=="create" && $_REQUEST['action']=="insert") {

$targeti = 1;
while(true) {
    if(isset($_POST['target'.$targeti])) {
        $target = $_POST['target'.$targeti];
        echo $target;
        echo "<BR>";
        $targeti++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
}
```

Any help you can give me would be highly appreciated.

Comment: **Do not post your database connection information like host, username and password on a public webpage!**

Comment: use name="targets[]" for alle the target inputs, and it return an array where you can loop trough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over $_POST['target'] because it doesn't exist. You need something like that:

```
$targeti = 1;
while(true) {
    if(isset($_POST['target'.$targeti])) {
        $target = $_POST['target'.$targeti];
        // process $target value here
        $targeti++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
}
```

and the same code for other types

EDITED: If you don't want to process value of $target inside the loop, you can save it in array ($targets[] = $target). The main idea of processing it in loop or saving in array is that if you'll create variables dynamically (${'target'.$targeti} = $_POST[...]) then you'll need to save counter variable ($targeti) and use it later to find all created variables, and such code it not clear.

Comment: Thanks for this code. However this causes the site to loop and not load the page Error 500. Any Ideas why?

Comment: Please look on updated code. I forgot to add break statement. Sorry about that

Comment: Can you add var_dump($_POST) to your question? I can't understand now why is doesn't work

Comment: Add dump just like another piece of code. Also try to add die('end') after while loop to see is problem occurs after loop or inside it.

Comment: Fixed it my server was automatically quiting. Do not know why but rectified it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your php code you are not doing any mysql insert actions. Also `$targeti = "2";` should be something like `$targeti++;` otherwise you always loop with `target2`.

Comment: the reason i have not included the insertions because it is no identifying the $_post's in an echo which i do further down the page. that is when it inserts it. (if the posts exist)

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I'll confirm.

HTML should be written as:

```
<textarea name="target []" id="target" class="validate[required]" style="margin:4px; max-width:400px; width:400px; max-height:35px; height:35px;"></textarea>
```

that way your values are uploaded as an array.

and the PHP for that would be:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['target'])) {  
         $target = $_POST['target'];            
         foreach($target as $targetvalue){  
            echo $targetvalue; // do something with the target value here.  
        }
     } 
?>
```

Comment: Why are you assigning the values to a local variable, only for looping? There really isn't a reason, right?

Comment: Name attribute must be "target[]" not id, because browsers send name to server

Comment: My bad. Wrote that in a rush . Thanks . Does it solve the problem?